# Jenkins Active Directory blocked myself

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i have a little problem i installed the Active Direcory Plugin in combination with role based strategy. Now i can login with Active Direcotory Users but not anymore with local users. How i can login with Local-Jenkins-Users to Jenkins ?

The local Users are already in the Role-based-strategy with admin permission.

Are anything possible like login locally e.g. .\ since Windows Login without a Domain

Answer (score 1):

I read some articles and I think you can't mix two kinds of strategy (local + AD).

The best option is to change the authorization stragegy like bellow:

[image]

Next, add some permissions/roles to your AD account.

Switch again on the `Role-Based stragegy` and you should be able to use your AD account.

Comment: Thank you :) Do you know how i can change the Default Path to Jenkins in Linux i read and try a few articles and everytime i get the following Error from Jenkins GUI :  
message             : com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy
converter    : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
line number         : 14

Comment: What do you mean by "Default Path to Jenkins"? It's the path to the Jenkins home folder?

Comment: Yes exactly i become every time the following error see : https://pastebin.com/1LN7f3BM

Comment: The Jenkins path is set by the JENKINS_HOME environment variable. By default on Linux, Jenkins is installed in the /var/lib/jenkins folder.